# Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли библиотеки для карусели на angular, есть ли какие то примеры?

Tags: angularjs

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли библиотеки для карусели на angular, есть ли какие то примеры? Поделитесь ссылками и примерами

Comment: http://ngmodules.org/tags/carousel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В модуле *ui-bootstrap* есть директиву `uib-carousel` ([ссылка](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel)). Вот пример:

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module('myApp').controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.carousel = {
        interval: 5000,
        slides: [
            {image: '//lorempixel.com/600/300/transport/1'},
            {image: '//lorempixel.com/600/300/transport/2'},
            {image: '//lorempixel.com/600/300/transport/3'},
            {image: '//lorempixel.com/600/300/transport/4'}
        ]
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<uib-carousel interval="carousel.interval" class="carousel-demo">
    <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in carousel.slides" active="slide.active">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
    </uib-slide>
</uib-carousel>
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uWrl9pXt3nPdwRV69H0U?p=preview)**